# Entity Framework doesn't return geography column on update from database

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, geospatial

I've just been given a task of adding a table to a SQL Server 2012 database. This table has a geography column:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[GeoStates]
(
    [Id] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [GEOID] [CHAR](5) NULL,
    [STATE] [NVARCHAR](50) NULL,
    [GEO_OBJECT] [GEOGRAPHY] NULL
)
```

The DAL project is ASP.NET 4.0 and built in VS2010, Entity Framework version is 4.4.0.0, runtime version: v4.0.30319.

When I import this table via 'update from database', VS imports all columns except the geography column.

Is it possible with what I'm working with, if so, how can I accomplish this? If not, what is the earliest version of EF that will do this and will it mean updating the ASP.Net version as well, how high does VS2010 go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mention with the problem of the version, not sure if you can update the EF to 6, another solution could be to create an stored procedure.

Check this link [spatial datatype](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework5/spatial-datatype-in-entity-framework5.aspx)

The EF version should be 6

You could add it manually using the `System.Data.Spatial.DbGeography`.

```
   public System.Data.Spatial.DbGeography Location { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks Christina, looks like it's decision time for upgrading frameworks, fingers crossed!